# how pass base64encode characters in codeigniter url?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have URL like this `http://domain/home/activate/MzU=` .the parameter

```
 "MzU=" = base64encode($data)
```

I cant open this URL with this parameter.
Error like this!`"The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."`
How can i pass base64encode characters in codeigniter url?

Comment: Why, what happens? How bug is `data`?

Comment: $data is an integer. activate is function and mzu= is parameter

Comment: Okay (there's a limit on the maximum length of GET paramters). So what happens, what doesn't work? What errors do you get where?

Comment: Pass it as `urlencode(base64encode($data))`. You could also add `=` to the config variable `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in `application/config/config.php`. But the first approach would be preferrable.

Comment: thank you air4x. now code is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the character "=" to $config['permitted_uri_chars'] in your config.php file which is available in your application/config directory

Comment: In many case only add character to config file is not enough. Suppose to add '@' to url you have to add characters in _clean_input_keys($str) function which is available in system/core/Input.php file.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a helper with the following functions:

```
function url_query_encode($array = array())
{
    return str_replace('/', '_', rtrim(base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($array))), '='));
}


function url_query_decode($str = '')
{
    return (is_string($str) && strlen($str)) ? @unserialize(gzuncompress(base64_decode(str_replace('_', '/', $str)))) : FALSE;
}
```